# Is the Nissan Skyline 350GT (Infiniti G35) brake self-adjusted?

Tags: brakes, nissan, infiniti, g35

I bought a service package for my Nissan Skyline 350GT (aka [Inifiniti G35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Skyline#V35.2FCPV35)) coupé including brake adjustment. However, I was told by my mechanic that the 350GT brake is self-adjusted so it doesn't need to be adjusted.

1. Does my car have self-adjusting brakes?
2. Will my car ever need the "brake adjustment" service?
3. How do self-adjusting brakes work?
4. Do most cars have this self-adjustment mechanism ?

Comment: What year is your car?

Comment: its 2005 350GT coupe.

Comment: I would split the "how does this work?" part into a separate question.

Comment: What? A dealer selling things that aren't necessary? Say it ain't so!